# Why does the Gallium-Aluminum Reaction Happen?

Tags: metallurgy

There a plenty of videos online of a small gallium sample being placed on a large aluminum sample, resulting in the former being absorbed by the latter and forming an extremely brittle alloy. What I cannot figure out is **why** this happens. Usually the explanation is something like the ["gallium atoms invade the aluminum"](https://sites.psu.edu/passionmalencia/2013/04/16/gallium/#:%7E:text=When%20gallium%20is%20placed%20on%20aluminum%20%28and%20the,of%20mercury%20because%20gallium%20is%20much%20less%20toxic.), but I find that very hand-wavy. It does not address why gallium is able to enter the aluminum crystalline structure so easily or how it diffuses throughout the aluminum sample so fast.

My only guess is that is has something to do with both metals being in group 13 on the periodic table has something to do with it. However, copper and silver are both in the same group and, as far as I know, placing a silver sample on a copper ingot does not result in the ingot absorbing the silver.

Just to be clear, my question is not about why a gallium-aluminum alloy is weak. My question is why is that alloy so easy to form.

Comment: Well, gallium is usually added to the aluminum as a liquid.  Your example of placing a silver sample on a copper ingot may turn out differently if the silver were molten.

Comment: I considered that gallium is a liquid being important to the reaction, but I don't see how. You could say that gallium can enter the aluminum sample easily because the interatomic forces between the gallium atoms are very weak [i.e. the sample is liquid], but that does not explain everything. Once the gallium atoms enter the aluminum they are no longer a liquid, yet they still diffuse through the entire aluminum sample.

Comment: Gallium is soluble along grain boundaries in the (polycrystalline) aluminum metal. Many elements are more soluble on grain boundaries than in the bulk. Grain boundaries also can dramatically enhance diffusivity. Finally, Ga saturating the boundary weakens it, allowing the material to fall apart along those weakened grain boundaries.

Comment: Also it helps to look at it the other way round: Al is soluble in Gallium! Whereever dissolved Al leaves a hole in the bulk (firstly and primarily at the grain boundaries), Ga can take its place. And so on. The alloy is still very close to its melting point (if it is already solid at all, that's hard to discern in such microscopic structures), so the mobility of the constituent atoms is pretty high.

Comment: BTW, a drop of mercury on gold *immediately* alloys, leaving a "silvery" looking stain on the gold. In a matter of hours, the mercury diffuses throughout the whole gold object, and the stain effectively disappears. This amalgam is *not* extremely weak, and does not destroy the object. However, "Gallium does not crystallize in any of the simple crystal structures. " (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium) and this makes its alloys quite weak. As for metals allowing other material to flow through, consider Pd and H2: https://www.peakscientific.com/discover/articles/hydrogen-purification-methods/